# How to do navigation after button has been clicked using angular material 2 tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular material 2 tabs and i wanted to have next button in one tab which navigates to another tab after clicking it. What should i need to use to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its preety simple :

```
<mat-tab-group class="demo-tab-group" #matgroup>
    ....
</mat-tab-group>

<button (click)='matgroup.selectedIndex = 2'>Go Next</button>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-trigger)**